# How to create EJB 2.1 beans in Eclipse 3.5

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-3.5, ejb-2.x

I am not able to create EJB 2.1 beans using a wizard in the latest version of Eclipse. I only see options to create EJB 3.0 beans.

I selected 2.1 as the 'EJB Module Version' while creating the "EJB Project". But now when I want to create a session bean, I don't see any option to create a 2.1 bean.

Is there a plugin/setting I need to enable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jst.ejb.doc.user/topics/tecrte.html) the only way to create EJB < 3.0 in eclipse 3.5 is creating with XDoclet (I've never done before).

Comment: this is bad from Eclipse

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's right, you can do it only with XDoclet, so in eclipse preferences, handle the xdoclet libraries, and choose XDoclet Entreprise Bean during EJB creation.

XDoclet will aim you to create all required classes and files.

Good luck.